# Carregamento de grande volume de dados com NHibernate + Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate

Eu utilizo o ORM NHibernate em um projeto windows forms e existe uma previsão de se trabalhar com um grande volume de dados em várias tabelas, variando de 1 a 15 mil registros em média. Embora não seja um volume de dados tão grande, como alguns podem falar, esta comprometendo o desempenho da aplicação quando é necessário popular um DataGridView com uma listagem completa de uma destas tabelas.

As minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. Qual a melhor forma de fazer o carregamento de TODOS esses dados?
2. Como popular o DataGridView ao criar um form sem que ocorra um Delay na sua abertura?
3. Alguém já usou Nhibernate com Reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Qual a melhor forma de fazer o carregamento de TODOS esses dados? Como popular o DataGridView ao criar um form sem que ocorra um Delay na sua abertura?

Paginando a DataGridView. [Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9504739/1314276) do SO gringo tem um exemplo o qual reproduzo traduzido abaixo:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExemploPaginacao
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int totalRegistros = 15000;
        private const int tamanhoPagina = 50;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { DataPropertyName = "Index" });
            bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindingSource1;
            bindingSource1.CurrentChanged += new System.EventHandler(bindingSource1_CurrentChanged);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = new ListaPaginada();
        }

        private void bindingSource1_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Este evento prepara um novo conjunto de registros quando o Current (propriedade que indica o registro atual da Grid é mudado
            int deslocamento = (int)bindingSource1.Current;
            var registros = new List<Registro>();
            for (int i = deslocamento; i < deslocamento + tamanhoPagina && i < totalRegistros; i++)
                registros.Add(new Registro { Index = i });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = registros;
        }

        class Registro
        {
            public int Index { get; set; }
        }

        class ListaPaginada: System.ComponentModel.IListSource
        {
            public bool ContemColecaoDeListas { get; protected set; }

            public System.Collections.IList GetList()
            {
                // Retorna uma lista de deslocamentos de página baseada em "totalRegistros" and "tamanhoPagina"
                var deslocamentosPaginas = new List<int>();
                for (int deslocamento = 0; deslocamento < totalRegistros; deslocamento += tamanhoPagina)
                    deslocamentosPaginas.Add(deslocamento);
                return deslocamentosPaginas;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Alguém já usou Nhibernate com Reactive?

Você pode melhorar esta parte da pergunta? Essa parte é baseada em opiniões e não cabe uma boa resposta, portanto.